# Can't understand the logic of F# mutable variable inside function body

Tags: f#

I'm learning F# and get stuck with the concept of `mutable` keyword.

Please see the below example:

```ml
let count =
    let mutable a = 1
    fun () -> a <- a + 1; a

val count: unit -> int
```

Which increases by 1 every time it's called with `()`. But next code does not:

```ml
let count =
    let mutable a = 1
    a <- a + 1
    a

val count: int
```

Which is always `2`.

In the book I'm studying with, it says with the first example, "The initialization of mutable value `a` is done only once, when the function has called first time."

When I started learning FP with haskell, the way it handled side effects like this totally burnt my brain, but F# `mutable` is destroying my brain again, with a different way. What's the difference between above two snippets? And, what's the true meaning and condition of above sentence, about the initialization of mutable value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your second example

```
let count =
    let mutable a = 1
    a <- a + 1
    a
```

Defines a mutable variable initialised to 1, then assigns a new value (a + 1) to it using the `<-` operator before returning the updated value on the last line. Since `a` has type `int` and this is returned from the function the return type of the function is also `int`.

The first example

```
let count =
    let mutable a = 1
    fun () -> a <- a + 1; a
```

also declares an `int` a initialised to 1. However instead of returning it directly it returns a function which closes over `a`. Each time this function is called, a is incremented and the updated value returned. It could be equivalently written as:

```
let count =
    let mutable a = 1
    let update () =
        a <- a + 1
        a
    update
```

`fun () -> ...` defines a [lambda expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/functions/lambda-expressions-the-fun-keyword). This version returns a 1-argument function reflected in the different return type of `unit -> int`.

Comment: Then why is the initialization of `a` is called only once in the first example? Does it have something to do with *pre-computation*? As I understood, calling the first one many time would cause initialization each time, which will make return value to be always `2`.

Comment: @MyBug18 - `a` is only initialised once in both examples because `count` is only evaluated once. It's hard to say without seeing the book you're refering to you but that behaviour is not special to mutable variables. You can see it with for example: `let count = printfn "initialising"; 1`

Answer (score 3):

The first example of `count` initializes a mutable variable, and returns a closure around this variable. Every time you call that closure, the variable is increased, and its new value returned.

The second example of `count` is just an initialization block that sets the variable, increases it once, and returns its value. Referring to `count` again only returns the already computed value again.